# Extract every frame form a variable-frame-rate video with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, multimedia

I'm trying to extract all the frames on several videos. Those videos were captured on a camera that saves the output with a **variable frame rate**, thus, some frames are closer together in time than others (from ~27 to ~30 fps according to *mediainfo*)

This frames are to be synchronized with some metadata, so I not only need to extract them but also keep the information of the [relative] time each frame of the video has been shot.

I've been using ffmpeg to extract video frames, the challenge comes when the video frame rate is not constant any more. Any other method or program different than ffmpeg is ok as far as it can get the job done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ffprobe to display the presentation time stamp (PTS) of every 'packet'

```
ffprobe -show_entries packet=pts_time,duration_time,stream_index file.mp4
```

Comment: It did the job! Didn't work on Ubuntu but on Windows it did :)